# Android windowBackground in theme not working - Splashscreen

Tags: android, user-interface, splash-screen

I'm trying to add splash-screen to my Android app.

I've been following instructions from [here](https://tech.pic-collage.com/show-logo-in-the-splash-screen-without-any-delay-95bbca56b86a). It's the standard way as I get it, and it seems logical.

So it's really simple right? Create drawable resource, use it in a theme as windowBackground, use the theme? Well it doesn't work for me...

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="euroicc.sicc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splashscreen">
        <activity android:name="euroicc.sicc.ui.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splashscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/main_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_default</item>


       <!--<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyAlertDialog</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Splashscreen" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen_drawable</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

splashscreen_drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splashschreen_eicc"
            android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I've tried other codes from other sites, but nothing seems to work.

Only white background is displayed for less then a second (approximately), and then the app starts running. I'm setting the theme AppTheme in onCreate method of main activity so it uses it's default theme always except on start.

I'm also overriding onPause and onResume, but I call their supers, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I'm testing on v7.0.0, but that shouldn't be a problem also?

I have more styles but I removed them from the example code, because they are used for dialogs and elements inside xml files, not for activities.

So what is the problem and how do I solve it? When I first read about splashscreens I thought setting windowBackground would've been enough

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine. Try clean -> build

Comment: @RahulKumar didn't work ):

Comment: tested your code on API 21, works fine. The only thing a bit unusual is that I would set `AppTheme.Splashscreen` only for the activity (and `AppTheme` for the the application). Anyway, I'd like to know what is wrong because it's exactly the method I use

Comment: @bwt yeah I know, but I'm desperate so I've put it everywhere in the manifest. Either way, I set a different theme on onCreate in Main Activity, so the app uses the correct theme.

Comment: So... Erm... It's working now. I literally done nothing. Just a weekend off work. I'm really at loss why this happened before, but now it's ok.

Comment: So... Erm... It's working now. I literally done nothing. Just a weekend off work. I'm really at loss why this happened before, but now it's ok.

Comment: @InvaderZim , I am pulling my hair. Im having this problem, and following all the instructions. Custom theme works, but as soon as I set `android:windowBackground` with a drawable value, boom... the content is skipped and the app opens directly with the main activity...

Answer (score 0):

You don't set your background in styles.xml, rather inside your splashcreen layout xml file. Here is my layout example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
android:background="@drawable/green"      ==============================> HERE!
tools:context=".activity_splash_screen">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/white_logo"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/title"
   />
```

If you need help with the entire code, I can help you!

Comment: I don't have a layout file for splashscreen but an xml file in drawables "splashscreen_drawable". I prefer this way, without using layouts, or using only layouts, styles (themes), other xml files and ofc manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem. I created the splash screen as a layer-list drawable, and in the theme as windowBackground as it is recommended everywhere, yet it wouldn't work on some devices (like my and my friend's Motorolas, a few other phones) - a black screen would be shown. For me the solution was to wrap my splash activity code in a Handler's postDelayed runnable with some small delay:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed( { //this is a trick so the splash screen - in window bg theme - is displayed on all devices, instead of black screen. E.g. moto g6
        val startMainActivityIntent = ...
        startActivity(startMainActivityIntent)
        finish()
    }, 100)
}
```

I am not particularly fond of delaying UI, if I knew a better way that worked, I would not do this. But it’s better than black screen.